# Auth::login doesn't persist the user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, authorization

here's the most basic code possible:

```
    Auth::login($user, true);
    var_dump(Auth::user());

    return redirect('/user');
```

on '/user' url I'm doing just var_dump(Auth::user());

In the first vardump I see correct user and everything is fine, on the second though, I get null. I have no idea why it's losing session. Any ideas?

Both urls are in the web.php and I'm using Laravel Passport authentication tokens

@edit: after removing var_dump, the code works, I have no idea why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Auth::login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492203/laravel-authlogin)

Comment: Where is the `$user` variable coming from?